# Sort Core Data Entity by relationships

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, core-data

I am developing an app where I need to display an `UITableView` like this one:

[image: Tableview nodes]

I am using `Core Data` with one entity called **Node**, this entity has 3 `attributes` and 2 `relationships`. One `relationship` is `parent`, that relation points `Node` itself from one to one. The other relationship is `childs`(forgive me, I know is children, but I like words ending with **s** for one to many relationships). `Childs` points to `Node` with one to many relationship and inverse relation to parent.

[image]

The problem is that I don't know how to Sort the items in `fetchedResultsControler` for display them in the `TableView` like that picture.

Thank you

Comment: Does `Node` contain any attributes that could be used for sorting? I see your example is sorted by the order of months in the year, but there's nothing in `Node` that would enable sorting in that order. Does `Node` also contain something like a numeric month name, or some other unspecified field that would indicate the order?

Comment: Actually in the Node I am just going to store a String, well Title and Text. When I'll have all the model, I am going to display the tableView and also a Diagram or conceptual map using that model. So the answer to your question is no. I can't manage the query by the content. Thank you

Comment: Have you considered using sections to split your data into the seasons? You could apply a dynamic sort depending on the month (spelling) in code, or alternatively store a unique attribute against each entity that could be used to sort.

Comment: if you're using nodes as elements in the tableview, it sounds like you might have to dynamically generate the table instead of creating it using a fetchedResultsController in the objc pattern. What about fetching all parent nodes first (those without any parents), populating a table with it, then recursively adding in each level of child nodes and adding table rows to them?